# My Xamarin Android app keeps restarting itsself

Tags: android, xamarin

I've an app that checks version compatibility at startup from within the main activity's `OnCreate` function.  Since Android doesn't (to my knowledge) have a modal dialog, if the version is not compatible I show an `AlertDialog` via `AlertDialog.Builder` and set the neutral button action to shut down the app.  Unfortunately this causes the app to restart instead of shutting down.  Could someone help me get the app to shut down please?

This is being tested on Android 7.0, but also needs to run on Android 4.2.2.

```
public class Activity1 : FragmentActivity {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        if (!versionCheck.Success) { 
            ShowNotesReadonlyDialog("Version Incompatibility", versionCheck.Message, new Action(() => ShutdownApplication()) );
            return;
        }
    }


    private void ShutdownApplication() {
        this.Finish();
        // -- I've tried all the things below with the same result.
        //this.FinishAffinity();
        //this.Dispose();
        //global::Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(global::Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
    }


    private void ShowNotesReadonlyDialog(String title, String message, Action action) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View layout = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GenericTextViewLayout, FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.Id.GenericTextViewDialogRoot));

        dialog.SetTitle(title);
        dialog.SetView(layout);

        TextView label = layout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.GenericTextViewMessageLabel);
        label.Text = message;

        dialog.SetNeutralButton("Close", (o, e) => {
            if (null != action) {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            dialog.Dispose(); 
        });
        dialog.SetCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog window = dialog.Create();
        WindowManagerLayoutParams p = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
        p.CopyFrom(window.Window.Attributes);
        p.Width = 900;
        p.Height = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent;
        window.Show();

        window.Window.Attributes = p;
    }
}
```

I've placed breakpoints in several lifecycle events.  After calling `Finish()` the following events are called on the Activity:

1. `OnStop()`
2. `OnCreate()`
3. `OnStart()`

Additionally, the Activity disappears from the screen when `Finish()` is called, but pressing the "window manager" hardware key shows that the application is still running.  Tapping the window shows it on screen.

Comment: Is `Activity1` the main launcher Activity of the app?

Comment: @SushiHangover: Yes.

Comment: What's you mean "restarting itsself"? Restart the `Activity1`?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT: Yes.  `Activity1` restarts.  It restarts hidden, or in the background and is visually invisible.  But if you click the Window Manager hardware button (shows all running apps) you see it running.  If you click on it, it becomes visible.

Comment: When I click the `close` button, it just called `OnStop` --> `OnDestroy` method, I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT: Must be some part of the app totally unrelated then.  Thanks for trying to look into it.